# Updating text in markdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, simplemde

Coding a blog website, using SimpleMDE (Markdown editor) for writing Markdown.

In app.js ,

```
//EDIT BLOG - FORM
app.get("/blog/:id/edit", function(req,res) {
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect("/blog");
        } else {
            res.render("editBlog", {blog : foundBlog});
        }
    })
})

//UPDATE BLOG
app.put("/blog/:id", function(req,res) {
    req.body.blog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.body);
    var id = req.params.id;
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.blog,{new: true}, function(err,updatedBlog) {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect("/blog");
        } else {
            res.render("showBlog", {blog : updatedBlog});
})
```

On using SimpleMDE, it works fine.
[image]
But on clicking the "Edit" button, the changes are saved as such:
[image]

In editBlog.ejs,

```
    <div class="field">
    <label>Text</label>
    <textarea id="MyID" type="text" name="blog[body]"><%= blog.body %> </textarea>
  </div>
```

In showBlog.ejs,

```
<div id="main-blog-content"><%- blog.body %></div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMDE is designed for writing Markdown. As such, the editor will provide Markdown when a form is submitted or when the content is accessed. If you're looking to convert it to HTML, you'll need to do so with a parsing library. SimpleMDE uses [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked), if you want to maintain consistency with the preview window.

Here's how to use SimpleMDE's built-in parser to convert Markdown to HTML:

```
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE();
var html = simplemde.markdown("**Example** text");
```